# Service Bus not moving messages to Dead Letter Queue after Max Delivery Count exceeded

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I've enabled Dead Letter Queue for our Service Bus Queues but the message was not moved to the DLQ after message retries exceeded the maximum delivery count. How can I make the message go to DLQ after message retries exceed the maximum delivery count?

I tried setting TTL to something low to see if the messages would get moved to DLQ, and they were. But maximum delivery count does not influence the moving of messages to the DLQ.

Specifics of the Queue:

- Max delivery count: 5
- Message TTL: unbounded
- Message Lock Duration: 1 minute
- Duplicate Detection: Enabled
- Duplicate Detection Window: 23 hours (for very
  long batch jobs)
- Dead Lettering: Enabled on message expiration
- Pricing Plan: Basic

How I tried testing the DLQ process:

1. Queued up a message to trigger our batch job process.
2. Allowed our receiver to lock the message & start processing (long job)
3. Killed our batch job process simulating a system failure
4. Restarted our batch job process allowing the message to be resent & job restarted.
   Observed the Retry count incrementing while watching the message in
   SB Explorer
5. Repeated the killing & restarting our batch job process (receiver) five times to exceed the Maximum Delivery Count

Upon exceeding Max Delivery Count, the message was removed from the Queue, and not moved to the DLQ.

Comment: Do you have auto-forwarding on the DLQ by any chance? Try to reproduce this w/o duplicate detection turned on. DLQ is a foundational feature. It's unlikely to be broken. And if still failing, I'd suggest re-creating your queue to rule out anything weird.

Comment: Clarification: We don't have forwarding on DLQ.  Will try disabling the duplicate detection and re-creating the queues per previous comment. Tyvm!